# Creating a Grouped Product with a max quantity for all sub-products

Tags: magento2, product, custom-options, grouped-products

I'm currently doing a food-package website in Magento 2 & I would like to be able to create a Grouped Product (or relevant alternative) where you have a maximum quantity of sub-products you can select before checking out.

An example would be, like a special offer for a takeaway where you can pick like 8 sides. If I select one, I want the maximum amount I could purchase for every side to go down to 7.

I'm aware of the maximum quantity in cart, but that only affects that one product.

Is there a way I can achieve this, or a possible work-around?